# Jquery Get Matched Selector Text From Inside Function

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, get, selector

Is there any way to get the text of the selector that invoked some function (if it exists) from within the function?

For example

```
$('#foo, .bar').click(function() {

   // Here I want to figure out if there was a match on #foo, or .bar

});
```

Basically I want to have a compounded selector like the one above (http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) but be able to know which one was matched when I get inside the function.

Comment: To add some more detail as to why I want to do this:

Normally I could do something like $('#foo').click(...) and $('.bar').click(...) but that would make jquery search the DOM twice.

I assume combining the two would be much faster as only 1 (slightly more complex) search is made instead of two.

Thus by knowing which selector was matched, I could have 1 search being used to invoke various other distinct functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that info with the `event object`.

```
$('#foo, .bar').click(function(event) {

   if(event.target.id === 'foo'){
      alert('foo');
   }
   else if(event.target.className === 'bar'){
      alert('bar');
   }

});
```

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/8CACU/

Ref.: http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Comment: Would there be any way to distinguish selectors if you didn't necessarily know what they were beforehand or they were more complex?

EG: selector string being constructed programatically or one like $('#foo > .bar > input, '#foo > .boo > input')

In a case like that it would require a lot more effort to infer which one was matched.

Comment: @mrkcsc: In your "more complex" example, you still would only look for `event.target.tagName === 'INPUT'`. Your only way to distinguish is over the `event object` since your event handler is attached to each element.

Comment: Both selectors are on the input tagname though so you would have to do some additional checks to figure out which one of the two it was.

I had a feeling this was my only option though and as you say it is pretty much my only choice so I'll mark it as the answer, thanks for the help.

Comment: @mrkcsc: I guess you can avoid this problem completly. Sure, there might be times where you need to figure which element was clicked (but mostly on `event delegation`). I don't know why you need to go this way, but I'm sure you can change your logic/code to avoid it.

Comment: I can, as I commented originally, I just wanted to do it for performance reasons to minimize the number of times the DOM was searched (through one large compounded selector).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#foo, .bar').click(GOTEMM(event) {

   if(event.target.id === 'foo'){
      alert('foo');
   }
   elseif(event.target.className === 'bar'){
      alert('bar');
   }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $(this) inside the callback to get the actual element and access the attribute of the element that is used in the selector.

```
$('#foo, .bar').click(function() { 
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'foo')  {
        alert('foo handled');
    } else if($(this).hasClass('bar')) {
        alert('bar handled');
    }
});
```

jsfiddle sample: http://jsfiddle.net/us8r9/

Comment: Thank you, this is similar solution as posted by jAndy.  I was wondering if there was a way to access the selector text directly instead of having to infer it using the this or event object, but it seems not.